# Integration by Partial Fractions, using $\sqrt2$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, fractions

Integrate $$\int\frac{10x^2 + 13x + 9}{(x^2 - 2)(2x + 1)^2}\mathrm dx$$

The difficulty here is in $x^2 - 2$. In order to determine the coefficients A to D, $\sqrt2$ must be invoked, in factorizing. Firstly, put $x = \sqrt 2$, next $-\sqrt 2$, $-0.5$.
The coefficients come out as fractions, which is unusual.

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{10x^2+13x+9}{(x^2-2)(2x+1)^2}=\frac{x}{49(x^2-2)}+\frac{157}{49(x^2-2)}-\frac{2}{49(2x+1)}-\frac{20}{7(2x+1)^2}$$

For $\frac{157}{49(x^2-2)}$ only you need to use $\sqrt2$, but I think it's not so hard.

Comment: I guess the OP is thinking: to do integration by partial fractions, your partial fractions should have irreducible (over the reals) denominators.

Comment: @GEdgar Do you mean $\frac{1}{x^2-2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\left(\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{x+\sqrt2}\right)$?

Comment: Alternatively, for $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2-2}=-\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{2-x^2}$, you can try the substitution $x=\sqrt2\sin\theta$.

Comment: @George Law I think it's more harder.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the coefficient of $A$ of the term
$\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{2}}$ in the partial fraction expansion of $$f(x)=\frac{10x^2 + 13x + 9}{(x^2 - 2)(2x + 1)^2}$$ can be determined by  evaluating the limit
$$A=\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}} \left((x-\sqrt{2})\cdot\frac{(10x^2 + 13x + 9)}{ (x^2 - 2)(2x + 1)^2}\right)=
\left.\frac{10x^2 + 13x + 9}{ (x +\sqrt{2})(2x + 1)^2}\right|_{x=\sqrt{2}}=\frac{2+157\sqrt{2}}{196}.$$
Similarly for the  coefficient of $B$ of the term $\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2}}$ we get $\frac{2-157\sqrt{2}}{196}$.
Hence
$$\frac{A}{x-\sqrt{2}}+\frac{B}{x+\sqrt{2}}=\frac{(A+B)x+\sqrt{2}(A-B)}{x^2-2}=\frac{x+157}{49(x^2-2)}.$$
So far we have 
$$f(x)=\frac{x+157}{49(x^2-2)}+\frac{C}{2x+1}+\frac{D}{(2x+1)^2}$$
and it remains to find the coefficients of $C$ and $D$. They should be
$C=-2/49$ and $D=-20/7$.

P.S. According to your given answer there is a little typo in the integrand (replace $(x^2-2)$ with $(x-2)$). The the integral is easier:
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{10x^2 + 13x + 9}{(x - 2)(2x + 1)^2}\,dx=
&\int\left(\frac{3}{x-2}-\frac{1}{2x+1} -\frac{2}{(2x+1)^2}\right)\,dx\\
\\&=\ln\left(\frac{(x - 2)^3}{\sqrt{2x + 1}}\right) - \frac{1}{2x + 1}+c.
\end{align*}

Comment: The answer is ln((x - 2)^3/ln(2x + 1)) -- 1/(2x + 1)

Comment: I cannot get this answer. Numbers can be eliminated from the denominators, by multiplying through by 49, but not from the numerators.

Comment: Nor can I see where ln(x - 2)^3 comes from.  Any ideas?

Comment: @tony My (edited) answer is about your difficulty with the term $x^2−2$ at the denominator. What is $\ln((x - 2)^3/\ln(2x + 1)) - 1/(2x + 1) $? It is not the integral of $\frac{10x^2 + 13x + 9}{(x^2 - 2)(2x + 1)^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The lecturer who set this Q (back in 1981: First-year Maths subsid.) gave that as the answer..ln(x-2)^3 etc. Never finished the Q, which is why I'm doing it now. This guy didn't make many mistakes; but, suppose he was still human. Wondered why I couldn't get this answer. My ans includes 1/196; 157root2 (twice); ln(x - root2); 10/7--did get the 1/(2x + 1) bit, though! Would you be in the mood to produce a final ans--comparison and put mind at rest, please/

Comment: @tony See my P.S. in the edited answer. Are you happy with this explanation?

Comment: A typing error! Would you believe it? But; now, it all fits into place with the original ans that was given. Great. Thank you. Forgive me--What's PS and how do I find the edited ans? Cheers.

Comment: @tony P.S. means simply  the "post scriptum" at the end of the answer above. So do you have any other questions? BTW if you are new here take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi again. Thought "PS" had an esoteric meaning here. Tried the "new-look" Q: maddenly, kep getting 3ln(x-2) instead of ln(x-2)^3.

Comment: ...continuing...Could I prevail upon yourself to explain that part, please. Thank you

Comment: @tony $3\ln(x-2)=\ln((x-2)^3)$. They are the same!